# Missing buttons on AlertDialog | Android 7.0 (Nexus 5x)

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog, invisible, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to create an `AlertDialog` but the buttons are not showing. Only seeing this issue in Android 7.0:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons.");
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
});
builder.show();
```

[image: AlertDialog]

Comment: try writing `ok` without resource.

Comment: Tried it, not working

Comment: also, side point, use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() so you don't have to use @TargetApi...

Comment: This is happening with me too. Actually buttons are there if you press. But color is transparent/white.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: i think, it's a bug in android 7

Comment: Another bug in Nougat now is that if you used the Window class to resize your AlertDialog the buttons don't show up at the bottom of the AlertDialog but only at the bottom of the content.

Comment: Really quite impressive how the Android team loves to break existing functionality at will and make even the most mediocre task a pain.

Answer (score 36):

Indeed it seems that AlertDialog theme needs to be defined. An alternative approach to above would be to define AlertDialog theme in Application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- ... other AppTheme items ... -->
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then it is enough create `AlertDialog.Builder` only with `Context` parameter.

**Note:** The above seems to work only for `android.app.AlertDialog.Builder` and is not working for AppCompat builder (`android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder`, at least as of version *25.0.1*). In case of AppCompat builder, I had to pass theme ID as second parameter to Builder constructor to have buttons visible.

Comment: You just need to use `<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>` (without `android:`) to work for `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder` using just the `context` parameter

Comment: I've posted a similar solution which is working for me : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42950260/1568663

Answer (score 20):

So it turns out on Android 7.0 you have to provide a theme. At least, that's what I had to do.

```
    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored</item>
    </style>


    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me was in styles.xml:

```
<style name="LightDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#007fff</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>   
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="DialogButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">#007fff</item>                   
</style>
```

and in your program:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.LightDialogTheme);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom theme for Alert Dialog, and set `alertDialogTheme` in your app theme.

```
<!--Alert Dialog Theme -->
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!--If minimum API level is greater than or equal to 23, you can define the color of Title text separately  -->
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@SomeColor</item> 

</style>

<!--This is to style the buttons of alert dialog-->
<style name="DialogButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and finally, set the custom created theme to `alertDialogTheme` in Application Theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--To make the change global to application-->
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Tested for `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and the thing was that I wasn't using the support library for my AppCompatActivity, therefore I changed:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer,
Its about import problem. you need to select v7.alertDialog, not use app.alertDialog.

Please change your code to v7.alertDialog and you will show button color in nexus as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need use a theme, like this:

```
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder (Activity, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeMaterialDialogAlert);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom colour to button.
Below your code

```
builder.show();
```

Write this

```
Button bg = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
bg.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe its too late, but I hope someone would use this solution.
you can do it something like this: You should set onShowListenter to your alertDialog, inside this function you should getButton() and than setTextColor to it. An example:

```
alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface){
        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(R.color.black);
    }
});
```