# Customizing a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

The first image is what I want. The second is what I get

[image]

I have this class to create a dialog

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlertFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                // Set Dialog Icon
                .setIcon(R.drawable.androidhappy)
                // Set Dialog Title
                .setTitle("Alert DialogFragment")
                // Set Dialog Message
                .setMessage("Alert DialogFragment Tutorial")

                // Positive button
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })

                // Negative Button
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do something else
                    }
                }).create();
    }
}
```

In my view

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

.......

final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

.......

AlertFragment alertdFragment = new AlertFragment();
// Show Alert DialogFragment
alertdFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialogFragmentStyle);
alertdFragment.show(fm, "Alert Dialog Fragment");
```

This is my style file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerItemStyle
        </item>

        <!-- For each individual Spinner list item once clicked on -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
        </item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fld_txt_size</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/fld_txt_size</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/btn_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDialogFragmentStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:headerDividersEnabled">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

I've posted all the style to see if there's anything going wrong. Regardless that I would like the separator between the header and the body of the dialog I do not understand why the buttons do not appear.

Edit:

I read this

[Missing buttons on AlertDialog | Android 7.0 (Nexus 5x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621606/missing-buttons-on-alertdialog-android-7-0-nexus-5x/41191717)

and I realized that I need to define a style for my dialog.

In fact if I set this

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton</item>
</style>
```

and then initialize dialog in this way

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingActivity.this,R.style.dialog_theme);
```

I can see change of color and text. But which is property to show title, separator and buttons?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a customized layout.  You need to create an instance of Dialog. i.e. Dialog dialog = new Dialog; and set the contentview for that dialog: dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_customized_dialog_layout);
you can then create buttons inside that layout and initialize them.

Comment: I followed this tutorial http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-dialogfragment-tutorial/ and He not use setContentView.

Comment: where is your alertdfragment? you followed example for the first(left image) not for the right image which is the result of alertdfragment class.

Comment: My AlertFragment is his AlertDFragment class. Infact I can see icon.

Comment: where is your activity_main.xml file?

Comment: and your mainactivity? you need the activity_main.xml file inflated in mainactivity to show those buttons.

Comment: MainActivity.java contains only code to display dialog.  And in xml there are only button to raise event that show two different dialog.