# DialogFragment buttons pushed off screen API 24 and above

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-7.0-nougat, dialogfragment, multichoiceitems

I am making a custom `DialogFragment` that displays a selectable list of data.  The list is too long to fit on the screen without scrolling.  For up to API 23, everything seems to work fine, but when I test on API 24+, the DialogFragment's button's are no longer visible.  I looked at [Missing buttons on AlertDialog | Android 7.0 (Nexus 5x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621606/missing-buttons-on-alertdialog-android-7-0-nexus-5x), but that doesn't seem to apply because my buttons do show up when I reduce the amount of content in the list so that it all fits on the screen.  How can I make my buttons visible?

My onCreateDialog() method:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final View dialogView = View.inflate(getContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, null);

    builder.setView(dialogView)
            .setTitle(R.string.muscle_groups)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(Exercise.MUSCLE_GROUPS, selectionTrackingArray, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                    ...
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.affirmative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ...
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

[Buttons appear to be pushed off the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioKBc.png)

Let me know if any more info is needed.

Answer (score 4):

Do you happen to set message by using `setMessage()` method of `AlertDialog.Builder`, although your sample code doesn't use it?

Because if you have a content that doesn't fit screen, setting a custom view and message at the same time to an alert dialog builder has a side effect as you described.

To solve this issue add your message to your custom view, and don't set message text using `setMessage()` method, dialog buttons will be visible.

Hope this helps.